# Webkitgtk signal to detect redirect event to a URL that is invalid?

Tags: webkit, g++

As part of my C++ app, I'm needing to log into a web service which has an oauth2 login flow.  I'm wanting to use webkitgtk-3.0 to accomplish this however, I'm having trouble detecting the login is complete.

What I need to do is detect when the browser wants to redirect to "http://localhost:12345" before it actually attempts to do so.

I've tried looking at the answers from here:  [Webkit GTK :: How to detect when a download has finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724088/webkit-gtk-how-to-detect-when-a-download-has-finished)

But none of them work.  Unfortunately the final page loaded, is what is able to be loaded, not http://localhost:12345.  Since there is nothing listening on http localhost port 12345.  i.e. from my load_finished_cb:

```
static void load_finished_cb(WebKitWebView *web_view, WebKitWebFrame *web_frame, gpointer data) 
{
      printf("Finished downloading %s\n", webkit_web_view_get_uri(web_view));
}
```

The value printed above is in fact a url to my login service and not localhost:12345 as I'd hoped.

What I'm really after is a callback to pre-browse.  How do I detect that?
Is it even possible?  I know it is with webkit2, but I don't want to use webkit2.  I wan't to use webkit and there is a very good reason for that that I won't get into here.

FYI: Under webkit2 what I would do is:

```
g_signal_connect(web_view, "load-changed", ... );
```

And in the callback for load-changed detect WEBKIT_LOAD_STARTED and check the value for the URI.

Comment: Looks like load-error-callback is the best option.  After lots of testing, it's the only one that detected the redirect.